# get running domains info using python + libvirt

Tags: python, libvirt

I'm trying to do a simple script that will get various informations about running domains on a xen host.

So far, i have :

```
import libvirt
import pprint
conn = libvirt.open('xen:///')

for id in conn.listDomainsID():
    dom = conn.lookupByID(id)
    infos = libvirt.virDomainGetInfo(dom)
```

which gives me the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'virDomainGetInfo'
```

Which, according to the API (http://www.libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt.html#virDomainGetInfo) should at least return me something.

Any clue ? (i'm a python newbie)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation: http://www.libvirt.org/python.html

```
There is a couple of function who don't map directly to their C counterparts due to specificities in their argument conversions:

    * virConnectListDomains is replaced by virDomain::listDomainsID(self) which returns a list of the integer ID for the currently running domains
    * virDomainGetInfo is replaced by virDomain::info() which returns a list of
         1. state: one of the state values (virDomainState)
         2. maxMemory: the maximum memory used by the domain
         3. memory: the current amount of memory used by the domain
         4. nbVirtCPU: the number of virtual CPU
         5. cpuTime: the time used by the domain in nanoseconds
```

Comment: That means that `infos = libvirt.virDomainGetInfo(dom)` has to be `infos = dom.info()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

To get documentations about the libvirt APIs in python, use the inline help.

Start your python interpreter (just type `python` in the shell).

```
>>> import libvirt
>>> help(libvirt)
```

This should give you a detailed documentation on libvirt.

Answer (score 0):

```
import libvirt
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
conn = libvirt.open(name)
domain = conn.lookupByName(domain_name)
domain_config = ET.fromstring(domain.XMLDesc())
domain_disks = domain_config.findall('//disk')
```